# Just wondering is this loop overwriting the array each time

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
 While Not sr.EndOfStream
        line = sr.ReadLine
        If line.Contains("Year") Then
            currentYear = line.ToString
        ElseIf line.Contains("mandatory") Then
            moduleStats = "M"
        ElseIf line.Contains("optional") Then
            moduleStats = "O"
        ElseIf line.Contains("COM") Then
            modArray = line.Split(",")
            Dim i As Integer = modArray.Length
            ReDim Preserve modArray(modArray.Length + 1) 'ReDim statement to change the size of one or more dimensions of an array, 
            'Preserve you can resize that dimension and still preserve all the contents of the array

            modArray(i) = moduleStats
            modArray(i + 1) = currentYear.ToString()

            String.Join(",", modArray)
            MsgBox(String.Join(",", modArray))
        End If

    End While
```

I checked the contents of the array at the end and it only held the last records within the text file, which suggest that it is overwriting the array, how can i prevent this?

Comment: Why are you still fooling around with Arrays and ReDim Preserve statements instead of using a List(Of String)or Dictionary(Of String,List(Of String) what is easier to maintain/read and faster? Asking while looking at your last questions.

Comment: ok i am now using list of strings, can u access the index similar to the array? I want to access a particular string within the list

Comment: Yes, you can access a list like an array.

Comment: @Stefan: If you have further questions arising from using strong typed collections, ask another question that describes better what you are actually trying to achieve and accept one of the below answers here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to preserve all of the input into a single string or array, your approach isn't working.  You are going to overwrite the array each time through.  Use a `StringBuilder`, so that you can keep adding characters to your string without having to `ReDim` the same array over and over.

**EDIT:** As @TimSchmelter suggested, you can also use a `List<string>` to keep your input.

Answer (score 2):

On the 10th line above, you are setting `modArray` to the comma-delineated contents of the line.  This of course wipes out any contents it previously had.

Rename that to, say, lineArray.  On the 12th line, switch to using a different array to build your list line values.  Or better, an List(Of String), so you don't have to keep adding to the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not just creating your string like this, instead of splitting and then joining again?

```
line = line & "," & moduleStats & "," & currentYear
```

Then you would use a list of strings

```
Dim lines = new List(Of String)

While Not sr.EndOfStream  
    ' Get the information as you have shown above
    lines.Add(line)
End While
```